# Unsupported Media Type returned when using Paging on APIController marked Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

After adding paging to an API Controller, I now receive a json error with Unsupported Media Type.

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2.  I can work around the problem by commenting out the [ApiController] attribute on the Controller, but this is obviously not preferred and I would like to understand what the underlying issue is.

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult<BlogPost>> Get(ResourceParameters resourceParameters)
{
    return Ok(await _repository.GetBlogPostsAsync(resourceParameters));
}
```

```cs
// The problem is suppressed by commenting out the ApiController attribute
[Route("api/[controller]")]
//[ApiController]
public class BlogController : ControllerBase
..
```

The response

```
// 20190530081824
// https://localhost:5001/api/blog
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "0HLN4PRV4JD94:00000001"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change your code to this

```
[Route("api/[controller]/")]
[ApiController]
public class BlogController : Controller
```

and

```
public async Task<ActionResult<BlogPost>> Get([FromQuery] ResourceParameters resourceParameters) 
{ 
    return Ok(await _repository.GetBlogPostsAsync(resourceParameters)); 
}
```

Make sure to have FromQuery or FromBody depend on your object you submit

Comment: No, did not make any difference.

Comment: I was just opening in Postman.  I have worked it out.  Seems it's required as of 2.2 of add [FromQuery] in the controller, where as I did not have to before.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you edit it as below and I can accept it:     public async Task<ActionResult<BlogPost>> Get([FromQuery] ResourceParameters resourceParameters)
        {
            return Ok(await _repository.GetBlogPostsAsync(resourceParameters));
        }

Comment: @Tig2810 It's Okay